# Duplicate entry on INSERT after DELETE from table in transaction

Tags: mysql, magento, transactions

I'm looking for any ideas to explain (and prevent) the following:

1) We have a Magento reindex process (price or stock) that is failing from time to time with:

> exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '512723-1-1' for
>   key 'PRIMARY'' in /[omitted]/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:242

Full trace: https://gist.github.com/werdan/5255362

2) Magento reindex is done in transaction, which can be  sketched as following:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
INSERT INTO cataloginventory_stock_status SELECT * FROM cataloginventory_stock_status_idx;
COMMIT;
```

3) It should be impossible to break consistency of the table between DELETE and INSERT commands, nevertheless it happens.

We have checked that tables cataloginventory_stock_status and cataloginventory_stock_status_idx have identical keys and structure.

What else can be suggested as an explanation and solution?

Comment: Transactions are a tool to be able to rollback changes. They don't prevent other processes from reading or writing the tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is what many SQL dump tools do:

```
LOCK TABLES foo WRITE;
ALTER TABLE foo DISABLE KEYS;

INSERT INTO foo (foo_id, foo_name) VALUES (1, 'One'), 
    (2, 'Two'), 
    (3, 'Three');

ALTER TABLE foo ENABLE KEYS;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, [locks on tables are not transaction-safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html) and it is a well-known and widely used piece of code in Magento, so I don't think that it is a way to go, at least for me.

Comment: Please read carefully the document you've linked, it explains the precise limitations. There're only two ways to avoid race conditions: lock tables or completely shut down the site. You choose ;-)