# Delete then insert occasionally fails with duplicate key

Tags: php, mysql, insert, race-condition

We have a table that looks like this:

```
 appointment_id | team_id
----------------|---------
 1001           | 1
 1005           | 4
 1009           | 7
```

In this table `appointment_id` is the primary index and `team_id` is just a regular index.

The code for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `appointment_primary_teams` (
  `appointment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`appointment_id`),
  KEY `team_id` (`team_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

However, **occasionally** the below code fails:

```
// Even though it looks like we are making 2 different PDO connections here
// the return is the same instance of PDO shared by 2 instances of a class for
// running queries. (It is how our system allows 2 different prepared queries
// at the same time)
$remove_query = database::connect('master_db');
$insert_query = database::connect('master_db');

$remove_query->prepare("
    DELETE FROM `appointment_primary_teams` WHERE appointment_id = :appointment_id
");
$insert_query->prepare("
    INSERT INTO `appointment_primary_teams` (
        `appointment_id`,
        `team_id`
    ) VALUES (
        :appointment_id,
        :team_id
    )
");

// Looping through a list of appointment data
foreach($appointments as $appointment) {
    // Runs fine
    $remove_query->bind(':appointment_id', $appointment['id'], CAST_INT);
    $remove_query->run();

    // Occasionlly errors saying $appointment['id'] already exists
    $insert_query->bind(':appointment_id', $appointment['id'], CAST_INT);
    $insert_query->bind(':team_id', $appointment['team_id'], CAST_INT);
    $insert_query->run();
}
```

The exact error is:

```
Database Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1001' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

At first, I thought this was a race condition within our API where the user was double clicking a submit button, but our system logs all requests and I can confirm that the user is only sending 1 request.

I am assuming that this is failing due to some type of race condition within MySQL, however I am unsure of how to prevent it. If that's true, I *could* just tell the script to sleep for a few milliseconds, but that's not an ideal solution, because if the DB hangs at all the issue can come back.

**My Question:** What is causing this issue, and how do I prevent this error?

---

This for an Amazon RDS server (MySQL 5.6.27); PHP is version 7.0.27 running on Ngnix 1.13.9 on Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09.

**NOTE:** Some of the code has been changed to remove proprietary information and simplify the issue, however I have preserved all the functionality of the code.

---

## Update 1

To be clear, despite the code shown there is only 1 instance of a PDO connection in use. After the running [this code](https://pastebin.com/edRzwWyu) the connection IDs came back as the same, meaning that it's the same connection to MySQL.

## Update 2

This ended up being somehow a race-condition within MySQL itself; My best guess is the race condition is either in query queuing (where MySQL is returning to PHP before the query has run completely) or MySQL's in-memory indexes (where MySQL isn't updating the index by the time the next query is run)

I have done several versions of tests to try and make sure that's what's going on, and all the tests point to that. If I had to guess this could probably be fixed by one of AWS's configuration files, but at this point I have no choice but resort to the `REPLACE INTO` syntax as tadman has suggested.

Comment: This is why there's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. It's a single atomic transaction that can't fail like this. As a note this schema is pretty wonky. Why isn't this a field on the appointment table since there's no other data and duplicates aren't allowed?

Comment: True, but this is a situation where it's important that the cause is understood, and honestly this solution might cause more damage. Failing loudly for a short time is a lot better than failing silently for a long time.

Comment: Is the primary key column really not an incrementing serial, or is the SQL inaccurate? How do you prevent duplicates?

Comment: @Sorpigal It's actually a primary key from another table that is auto incremented. The code before this fetches it and uses it as the primary key for this table.

Comment: Is your database wrapper enforcing transactions? Could another writer be running in parallel with the same records "sometimes"? For something like this I would want a transaction around delete and insert.

Comment: Hmm, well it does support transactions. But I am pretty sure it's configured not to use them by default. I will double check that and get back to you.

Comment: Come to think of it transactions probably won't help (e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663626/duplicate-entry-on-insert-after-delete-from-table-in-transaction) because MySQL.

Comment: @Sorpigal Transactions are supported, but not used by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way to fix a race condition is to avoid having a sequencing problem in the first place. Replace the pair of queries with one query:

```
INSERT INTO `appointment_primary_teams` (
    `appointment_id`,
    `team_id`
) VALUES (
    :appointment_id,
    :team_id
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE team_id=VALUES(team_id)
```

This is an atomic operation and it will either insert a record or update an existing record, no `DELETE` required. This is a good general-purpose approach to maintaining these sorts of relationship records.

The alternative is the more heavy-handed `REPLACE INTO` approach:

```
REPLACE INTO `appointment_primary_teams` (
    `appointment_id`,
    `team_id`
) VALUES (
    :appointment_id,
    :team_id
)
```

This stomps any existing records. The down-side to this is it acts like an atomic `DELETE`/`INSERT` pair which allocates new `PRIMARY KEY` values if those are `AUTO_INCREMENT`. In your case it isn't, so this is not an issue.

The way you get race conditions like that is that the `INSERT` query must be running at the same time as the `DELETE` query. That's only possible if there's two connections, and that could be because there's two requests being received simultaneously that are both attempting to alter the record, or because the single instance is somehow running both queries in parallel.

Comment: As it's stated in the code comment above the `database::connect('master_db');`, this is the same pdo connection.

Comment: You say that but I'm not convinced as your problem is exactly what would happen if that assumption was wrong. Returning a prepared statement handle is just broken by design, so that has to be fixed at the absolute least.

Comment: Also, you are assuming the query class works like a traditional PDO prepare. This is not the case, this class was customized to avoid that.

Comment: You're going to have to show that code because if you're saying these are separate statements on the same handle then what you're describing is impossible.

Comment: `Database` is a connection manager, designed **specifically** to prevent redundant connections and **specifically** to use the same instance of a PDO connection. It has no other purpose than that. Beyond that, this issue is only happening about once in about 10,000 tries. If it were 2 different connections it would be close to once every 100 or so tries. I should know because I have solved several race conditions in our system because devs didn't use the `database` class properly. Assuming I am wrong because you can't think of anything else is a poor judgement at the least.

Comment: While I can't send you the actual class, I can show the method: https://pastebin.com/dB8m7tbb - Where `static::$connections[$id]` is an instance of PDO

Comment: Also, your assuming the handle is an extension of the [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) class, but it not. It's a class that abstracts all interaction with the PDO and PDOStatement classes away so that it's simpler to work with.

Comment: That bin's already been deleted so I can't tell you what's wrong. I think your class is the root of these problems, not the code you have here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167655/discussion-between-nicholas-summers-and-tadman).

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem using PDO directly rather than through your abstraction layer? There's something wrong here but it's hard to rule out probable causes because that snippet has additional abstraction in it.

Comment: Is it possible that 99% of the time they're the same connection but 1% of the time they're not? Does that abstraction layer have unit tests to verify it's working correctly? It looks like there's a lot of code in that which could go awry if not properly verified.

Comment: Due to the inconsistent nature of this problem I can't say when I will be able to get back to with a confirmation, but it is happening 2-3 times a day. I will setup the system to use a traditional PDO statement for this problem. If nothing happens within 72 hours I will concede that it's not with the queries themselves. Until then, please assume it's not the abstraction layer.

Comment: No, it's not really possible that it's different connections. Like I said, whenever a connection happens it's logged; both before and after the connection is made. And the logs for each time this happens say that it only connects once.

Comment: That's the problem with race conditions, they're not always easy to trigger. My instinct here is to get rid of the two query approach and have a single atomic statement that can do the required work. I've overhauled this answer accordingly. You simply can't have a race condition without parallel execution.

Comment: Thank you, I have retracted my flag. I will mark this as the answer to go with if I am unable to find an alternative or it does turn out to be connection related. However, I would much rather find out the cause and prevent/fix it than apply an atomic solution.

Comment: This could be a "Heisenbug" where you can either find the problem and have no idea how to fix it, or fix it and have no idea what was wrong.

Comment: After several thousand requests (4 of which produced a duplicate key error) the MySQL connection session IDs were never different. This issue is not related to multiple connections.

Comment: The only alternative is overlapping requests for the same record. Since there's no transaction locking here this is a race condition problem.

Comment: That was my first guess, but each request (failed or not) is logged, both before and after an API endpoint is run. No overlapping requests for the same record, at least not within 10 seconds of the requests in question.

Comment: You're going to have to try and reproduce this problem as a minimal self-contained example because what you're describing is extremely unusual and defies all explanation.

Comment: Here's your explanation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/concurrent-inserts.html

Comment: Specifically: "If there are multiple INSERT statements, they are queued and performed in sequence, concurrently with the SELECT statements. The results of a concurrent INSERT may not be visible immediately."

Comment: I realize it says "insert" and we are talking about a "delete", but MySQL has a tendency to treat deletes and updates like inserts. I can't 100% confirm that's what's going on until after I update the configuration, but I am betting that's what's going on.

Comment: It's an "insert" in that a `DELETE` adds things to the journal, this is how MVCC works, but those should be committed and folded into the main version when the transaction is closed.